# Why are the d3 Bl.ocks gist examples showing incomplete code for the HTML5 page?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Reference: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318

I am trying to use and tweek examples from this extensive library, but most of the examples have incomplete code. There are not only plenty of html tags missing, but it appears "cut-off" after the closing script tag. And there is no reference to any specific libraries to make it work. I tried a few, guessing, and no luck. I went to the "About Page" and no luck there either.

For example, the one above has the following code given in the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.day {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #ccc;
}

.month {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 2px;
 }

 .RdYlGn .q0-11{fill:rgb(165,0,38)}
 .RdYlGn .q1-11{fill:rgb(215,48,39)}
 .RdYlGn .q2-11{fill:rgb(244,109,67)}
 .RdYlGn .q3-11{fill:rgb(253,174,97)}
 .RdYlGn .q4-11{fill:rgb(254,224,139)}
 .RdYlGn .q5-11{fill:rgb(255,255,191)}
 .RdYlGn .q6-11{fill:rgb(217,239,139)}
 .RdYlGn .q7-11{fill:rgb(166,217,106)}
 .RdYlGn .q8-11{fill:rgb(102,189,99)}
 .RdYlGn .q9-11{fill:rgb(26,152,80)}
 .RdYlGn .q10-11{fill:rgb(0,104,55)}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 136,
    cellSize = 17; // cell size

var percent = d3.format(".1%"),
    format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");

var color = d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain([-.05, .05])
    .range(d3.range(11).map(function(d) { return "q" + d + "-11"; }));

var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
    .data(d3.range(1990, 2011))
  .enter().append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("class", "RdYlGn")
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((width - cellSize * 53) / 2) + 
    ","     + (height - cellSize * 7 - 1) + ")");

 svg.append("text")
     .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + cellSize * 3.5 + ")rotate(-90)")
     .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });

var rect = svg.selectAll(".day")
    .data(function(d) { return d3.time.days(new Date(d, 0, 1),
     new Date(d     + 1, 0, 1)); })
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "day")
    .attr("width", cellSize)
    .attr("height", cellSize)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d3.time.weekOfYear(d) * cellSize; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.getDay() * cellSize; })
    .datum(format);

rect.append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });

svg.selectAll(".month")
    .data(function(d) { return d3.time.months(new Date(d, 0, 1), 
new Date(d + 1, 0, 1)); })
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "month")
    .attr("d", monthPath);

d3.csv("dji.csv", function(error, csv) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var data = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.Date; })
    .rollup(function(d) { return (d[0].Close - d[0].Open) / d[0].Open; })
    .map(csv);

  rect.filter(function(d) { return d in data; })
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "day " + color(data[d]); })
    .select("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d + ": " + percent(data[d]); });
});

function monthPath(t0) {
  var t1 = new Date(t0.getFullYear(), t0.getMonth() + 1, 0),
      d0 = t0.getDay(), w0 = d3.time.weekOfYear(t0),
      d1 = t1.getDay(), w1 = d3.time.weekOfYear(t1);
  return "M" + (w0 + 1) * cellSize + "," + d0 * cellSize
      + "H" + w0 * cellSize + "V" + 7 * cellSize
      + "H" + w1 * cellSize + "V" + (d1 + 1) * cellSize
      + "H" + (w1 + 1) * cellSize + "V" + 0
      + "H" + (w0 + 1) * cellSize + "Z";
}
</script>
```

Comment: In your opinion, what tags are missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember asking me the same question when I first stumbled upon this: *Why on earth would anyone put up an example with incomplete code?* It really looks cut off as if something was missing to the end. Diving into the spec and giving it a second thought, things clear up, though.

The `index.html` seems to be missing the

```
  </body>
</html>
```

closing tags to  make it a complete HTML 5 file. Looking at the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags), however, one notices that this will only make it pleasing to the eye, there is no technical requirement for these tags:

> *8.1.2.4 Optional tags*
>
> An `html` element's end tag may be omitted if the `html` element is not immediately followed by a comment.
>
> A `body` element's end tag may be omitted if the `body` element is not immediately followed by a comment.

That being said, the code as it is, is both complete as well as valid. It's all in there: the styles, the code, the external references. You don't need anything beyond what you see.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed, I need to take a close, hard look at the html spec before I fly off the handle making assumptions. BTW, for whatever reason, when I first loaded this in CodeLobster, it wouldn't render in the "preview", but when I tried it in AptanaStudio3, it did so nicely. Anyway, what was I thinking?!?!  ;-)   Thanks again!

Comment: Shall I call this a "wrap"? And would I answer my own question by doing so? How does that work?